# how is this survey made?

Tags: flash, survey

Does anyone know how this survey is made? And how something like it can be created?
I know it's made with Flash but how do they export the results to a shopping cart? Have a client that would like something created similar to this.

Thanks

www.vitaminid com

Answer (score 1):

While you fill out the form the selected answers are stored in Flash.  When you click submit at the end of the survey the Flash movie generates XML in the form:

```
<Survey Status="1" NavPosition="">
  <UserInfo Name="sberry2a"/>
  <Questions>
    <Q QId="1" TypeId="1" Answer="1"/>
    <Q QId="2" TypeId="3" Answer="02/1979"/>
    <Q QId="3" TypeId="3" Answer="67"/>
    <Q QId="4" TypeId="4" Answer="180"/>
    <Q QId="5" TypeId="1" Answer="2"/>
    <Q QId="6" TypeId="1" Answer=""/>
    <Q QId="7" TypeId="1" Answer=""/>
    <Q QId="8" TypeId="3" Answer="3"/>
    <Q QId="9" TypeId="3" Answer="2"/>
    <Q QId="10" TypeId="3" Answer="3"/>
    ...
    etc
    ...
  </Questions>
</Survey>
```

This XML gets posted to http://www.vitaminid.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/GetSurveyResult?storeId=201&flash=true which is most likely a Java servlet that parses the XML and based on the results makes recomendations.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks that's the best answer I received anywhere. Is this something hard to create? Appox how much something like this would cost? Your answer is very much appreciated

Comment: As far as how "hard to create" it is... it depends on your skill level in Flash and backend programming technologies.  All-in-all this doesn't seem like something all that difficult - but like I said, it all depends on your level of experience.